# Where is the 1.9.0 update secret level

Tags: wheres-my-water

The new 1.9.0 where's my water update says in its description:

> To celebrate the release of "Swampy's Underground Adventures" – Disney's new Youtube series based on Where's My Water – we've updated with a new hidden level! Here's a hint: Look for the Fire Extinguisher! Additionally for all of those Mystery Duck owners, enjoy 20 new levels!

How do I access that secret level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually in the collection section for swampys story. Head all the way to the bottom and you'll see 2 carvings the first is a sun which is a level called "good morning" the other is the fire extinguisher and that has the new hidden level "underground". Click on either and enjoy :-)

After you scroll all the way down, drag the screen up past the scroll amount. You should see the extinguisher.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see the sun, but I can't find the fire extinguisher, could you please add a screenshot.